# Set keyboard focus

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, methods, focus

I'm currently following a java tutorial on how to create a guessing game GUI App. At one point in the instructions however, it says to Set the keyboard focus to the field; I don't know what this means or how to do it. Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

here's the exact instruction: **Focus the user's attention on thePlayer field:
Set the keyboard focus to the field.**

here's my code so far:

```
public class GOM extends JFrame implements ActionListener, KeyListener
{
    Container content = this.getContentPane();
    //top
JTextField theGuess = new JTextField(10);
JLabel bankroll = new JLabel("");

//bottom
JButton newplayer = new JButton("New Player"); 
JButton newnumber = new JButton("New Number"); 
JTextField thePlayer = new JTextField(20);

//center
JTextArea theoutput = new JTextArea("");

//invisible
String playerName;
int theNumber;
int numTries;
int numGames;
double amtRemaining;

 Random randomizer()
{
  Random rnd = new Random();
  return rnd;
}
   JScrollPane scrollArea = new JScrollPane(theoutput); 



public GOM()
{
    this.setVisible(true);
       this.setSize(500,400);
       this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("Guess O'Matic");

        //top panel

        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.add(theGuess);
        p1.add(bankroll);
        p1.add(new JLabel("Make Your Guess"));
        content.add(p1, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        //bottom panel
        JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
         p2.add(newplayer);
         p2.add(newnumber);
         p2.add(thePlayer);
         content.add(p2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

         // finishing touches
         content.add(new JLabel("  "), BorderLayout.WEST);
         content.add(new JLabel("  "), BorderLayout.EAST);  
         content.add(scrollArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
         newplayer.addActionListener(this);
         newnumber.addActionListener(this);
         thePlayer.addKeyListener(this);
         theGuess.addKeyListener(this);

         newPlayer();
}
public void newPlayer()
{
    theoutput.setText(playerName);
    theoutput.setEnabled(false);
    theGuess.setEnabled(false);
    newnumber.setEnabled(false);
    newplayer.setEnabled(false);
    theGuess.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    thePlayer.setEnabled(true);
    thePlayer.setText(playerName);
    thePlayer.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
}
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) 
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) 
    {

    }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a GUI with several JTextFields and possibly other text components, the keyboard focus can only be on one of those fields at a time. In other words, if you type, only one of the fields can display the caret and then will usually display the typed in text. When a Swing GUI is displayed then the GUI must decide which text component should have focus, and it uses its focus traversal policy to decide this. The default policy usually will put the focus into the first text field created. **You** can change this by calling `requestFocusInWindow()` on the text component that you want to hold the focus.